# Can't fetch local json using typescript "useEffect" in my RN Project

Tags: json, typescript, react-native, fetch

```
const jsonUrlExternal = require('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json'); //this works
const jsonUrlLocal  = require('../../json/MOCK_DATA.json'); //this doesn't work
```

When i use the first `const jsonUrlExternal` my app works well and fetch the data in the JSON. But when i simply change the URL to a local path it gives me an error: `Type Error: Network request failed`. Below, the code i'm using to fetch both local and external JSON file:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(jsonUrlLocal) //the error appears exactly when i write this line
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
        .catch((error) => alert(error))
    })
```

And this is the `FlatList` i'm using to show the data from the JSON:

```
                <FlatList 
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <Text>
                            {item.title}, {item.realeseYear}
                        </Text>
                    )}
                />
```

In short: when i use an external JSON from an URL my FlatList works, but when i simply change the `URL` for a local `path/to/the/file/` the application returns me the error message: `Type Error: Network request failed`.
OBS: the content inside local JSON is exactly the RAW Copy of the ExternalJson. I'm sure that the local JSON has no typing errors.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just importing the JSON file normally (with top level import)? The file is already there you're not fetching it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `require()` a local `.json` file, what I would expect to happen is to get an object instead of an URL. Fetch would then stingify that object and make a request to `'[object%20Object]'`, which would naturally fail.

Since you've already `require()`d it, there is no need to fetch it. It's already parsed and ready to use.

```
const mockData = require('../../json/MOCK_DATA.json');



                <FlatList 
                    data={mockData}
                    keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <Text>
                            {item.title}, {item.realeseYear}
                        </Text>
                    )}
                />
```

Comment: Is there other way to use my local JSON in this simple project? I don't want to use external JSON because i'm building a CRUD, so the data will be stored locally. I tried to upload in a localhost and use the URL to acess the file, but i got `XX.XX/MOCK_DATA.json could not be found within the project`. Thanks for helping me. Also, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Depends on your build set-up a lot, but if you `require()`d the `.json` file, you can just use it as an object. You don't need to fetch it or anything.

Comment: Try `console.log()`ing `jsonUrlLocal` just after the `require()`. It should be an object (or array).